# Hibernate HHH000273: Error accessing type info result set : java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

Tags: hibernate, datasource, jndi

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">pk.org.cm.services.cs.utils.CustomDBSource</property>
```

Getting following warning on setting the above **custom JNDI DS provider**:

```
2014-01-07 08:53:58,237: [WARN ] org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity() - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!

2014-01-07 08:53:58,290: [INFO ] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure() - HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null

2014-01-07 08:53:58,379: [INFO ] org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider() - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: pk.org.cm.services.cs.utils.CustomDBSource

2014-01-07 08:53:58,470: [WARN ] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.TypeInfoExtracter.extractTypeInfo() - HHH000273: Error accessing type info result set : java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

2014-01-07 08:53:58,488: [INFO ] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init>() - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

2014-01-07 08:53:58,510: [INFO ] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder.useContextualLobCreation() - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

2014-01-07 08:53:58,820: [INFO ] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService() - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
```

Is there anything to worry about?